# Move the selected attribute in a select menu using jQuery

Tags: jquery, select

I have three product pages. Let's identify them as Hot Chocolate, Mocha Coffee, Espresso

Each page has a form at the bottom, with an identical select menu:

```
<form>
    <select class="ProductType">
        <option selected>(Please choose)</option>
        <option>Hot Chocolate</option>
        <option>Mocha Coffee</option> 
        <option>Espresso</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

There's also a surrounding div that contains a unique class value that identifies the page/product. For example:

`<div class="hot-chocolate"> ... </div>`

I can edit that outside `div` but I can't manually alter anything within the `form` tag.

Is it possible to use jQuery to move the `selected` attribute dynamically to the `option` that matches the page currently being viewed (ie. that in some way matches the class name of the surrounding div, even when the option value is a phrase with spaces)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following assumes you want to select the option with value "Hot Chocolate". Note the class name is case sensitive (must match the case of the option value)

Html (note `id` attribute added to the `<div>`

```
<div id="selection" class="Hot-Chocolate"> ... </div>
....
<form>
  <select class="ProductType">
    <option selected>(Please choose)</option>
    <option>Hot Chocolate</option>
    <option>Mocha Coffee</option> 
    <option>Espresso</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Script

```
var selection = $('#selection').attr('class').replace('-', ' ');
$('.ProductType').val(selection);
```

Refer [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4k5rfpaw/1/)

Comment: This worked thanks. I had a few further menu options, not shown above, that were three words long, so all I had to change was `replace('-', ' ')` to `replace(/\-/g, ' ');` in order for it to replace every instance of it.

Comment: You mentioned that you can edit the `<div>`. Another option would be to use `data` rather that a `class` attribute e.g. `<div data-selection="Hot Chocolate" ...>` and then `$('.ProductType').val($('#selection').data('selection'));` so you don't have to strip out the hyphen

Comment: Just been reading up on data-selection and it looks safe to use now. Excellent idea and a tidier solution - thanks.